# Do Gronwall-type inequalities hold for these inequalities involving $|X(t)|^{p}$?

Tags: inequality

Let $X(t)$ be an increasing function with $X(t)>1$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}^{+}=[0,\infty)$. Let $p\ge 2$ be an integer and $\alpha,\beta>0$ and $C>0$ are constants. Then if

$|X(t)|^{p}\le \alpha+\beta\int_{t_{i}}^{t}|X(s)|^{p}ds$

the Gronwall Lemma gives

$|X(t)|^{p}\le \alpha\exp(\beta\int_{t_{i}}^{t}ds)=\alpha\exp(\beta |t-t_{i}|)$

But now given the inequalities:

$|X(t)|^{p}\le \alpha+\beta\left[\int_{0}^{t}C(1+|X(s)|)^{p}ds\right]^{p/2}$

$|X(t)|^{p}\le \alpha+\beta\left[\int_{0}^{t}C(1+|X(s)|^{p})ds\right]^{p/2}$

$|X(t)|^{p}\le \alpha+\beta\left[\int_{0}^{t}C(|X(s)|^{p}ds)\right]^{p/2}$

or with $p>q$

$|X(t)|^{p}\le \alpha+\beta\left[\int_{0}^{t}C(1+|X(s)|)^{q}ds\right]^{p/2}$

$|X(t)|^{p}\le \alpha+\beta\left[\int_{0}^{t}C(1+|X(s)|^{q})ds\right]^{p/2}$

$|X(t)|^{p}\le \alpha+\beta\left[\int_{0}^{t}C(|X(s)|^{q}ds)\right]^{p/2}$

Can one establish/prove that these (or at least any one of them) lead to Gronwall-type inequalities such that

$|X(t)|^{p}\le \alpha\exp(...)$